# Can continuity by sequences be applied?

Tags: general-topology

I have a rather short question:

If I have a compact topological space that is induced by a metric and I want to show continuity of a function on that topological space:  Can I then use the criterion using limit of sequences?

Or is that only for metric spaces?

Comment: Induced by a metric is just another way to say metrizable.

Answer (score 3):

If the space is metrizable, then yes, convergence in the metric-induced topology is equivalent to convergence with respect to the metric. This follows from the fact that we can write any open set $U$ the union of open balls, i.e. $U = \bigcup_{x\in U}B(x; x_\varepsilon)$.

Comment: Yes. The topological space is compact and induced by a metric. Is it then metrizable?

Comment: Remember the definition of a metrizable topological space?